# Replacing fork and hydraulic brakes

Tags: fork, hydraulic-disc-brake, compatibility, build

I had a 2012 29er Giant Talon that got a bit trashed a few years back, so I bought a new bike which was recently ripped off.

As a result I am currently trying to get my Talon in working condition again, I have to replace both the hydraulic breaks. I was considering replacing them with the original Tektro Brake Disc Draco Hydraulic, but thought this might be a good chance to replace the fork as well.

I am now worried about getting into compatibility issues between new forks and new brakes.

Kind of a dumb question, but I was wondering what the best way to check compatibility is between these two parts when I am looking online, as well as if there are any suggestions for a sturdy, medium end hydraulic brake and fork that are compatible.

Comment: The new bike theft is irrelevant to the question.  Sorry to hear about it, but suggest that bit is edited out.

Comment: As someone who recently did the same proceedure, I would strongly suggest against doing this.  It will be cheaper to replace the bike then to get a new fork and brakes once you account for other things like your (probably) worn drive train.  Keep the Talon around for parts if you are so inclined or ride it as is.

Answer (score 2):

The brake (not break) / fork interface will be standard post mount and is the least of the problems. Adapters are readily availble so you won't have a compatibility problem that cannot be sorted for a few $$.

The other issues to watch for when switching forks from that era would be the steerer - Talon was probably 1/18th straight, but tapered are now far more common. Its possible to get adapters to fit straight forks into frames built for tapered, but not the other way round.

You will also need to match your wheel, or more accurately, axle. Likely the Talon had a 9mmQR, forks now comes in many variations of QR and though axle.

Therefore you want to find a disc compatible fork fork with the same steerer and axle mount as you already have.